# Implement the storage of messages in the chat (RPC)

Tags: database, chat, rpc, xdr

I must implement the chat using Sun RPC (first write XDR file, in the next place generate .c codes by dint of rpcgen). I would like to know how I should implement the storage of messages for users who are registered, but they were OFFLINE, when other users were writing. So that the user, when he will ONLINE, was able to read everything that was written without him in the chat. 
I write in Ubuntu. Thanks.
Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

As the name says, Xdr is for external data representation.

You can easily store the messages as string in a DB, and when an user logs in, you can create the xdr stream and send to him all messages.